# Extracting only tweets of a particular # hastag

Tags: python, tweepy

I am using python 3.4 , tweepy API to extract tweets to a text file but instead of only tweets the entire source of the page is being extracted. If there is a way to get the tweets only not entire source code .

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: So what have you tried so far? care to share your code of trials and errors?

Comment: api = tweepy.API(auth)
alltweets = [] 
new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200)
alltweets.extend(new_tweets)
oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
while len(new_tweets) > 0:
  print (" %s" % (oldest))
new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200,max_id=oldest)
alltweets.extend(new_tweets)
oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
print ("%s" % (len(alltweets)))
outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-8")] for tweet in alltweets]
with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'wb') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tweets come in formatted as JSON. So include simple JSON into your script to encode them. (btw this is python 2.7 so you will have to do the print differently)

```
from tweepy.utils import import_simplejson
json = import_simplejson()
```

Load each tweet with python, make sure that the data['entities]['hashtags] field is not empty (so it has a hashtag)

```
data_temp = json.loads(data)
if data_temp['entities']['hashtags']:
    tweet_text = data_temp["text"].encode('utf-8')
```

then print it out to file

```
print(tweet_text, file=write_file)
```

These are only snippets, use this guys script to help you get going and source the tweets. Big ups to him: https://github.com/bwbaugh/twitter-corpus

Comment: not able to find import_simplejson python module , getting  Name error

Comment: what values should be given in 'entities'

Comment: `entities` is a JSON value which contains `hashtags`. You're just checking that there are values in it indicating that there is a hashtag in the tweet. Then you save the tweet text from data_temp.

Comment: Is it import_simplejson or import simplejson ??

Answer (score 0):

Streaming API for twitter returns tweet for a given *word to be tracked* in JSON format.

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session
twitter_session = OAuth1Session(consumer_key,client_secret=consumer_secret,resource_owner_key=access_token,resource_owner_secret=access_token_secret)
streaming_tweets_objects = twitter_session.post('https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json',data={'track':query_word },stream=True)
```

Replace query_word with *hashtag* you are looking for.. Note that this also returns if hashtag is present in tweet text instead as a hashtag.
For hashtag , you can filter your results by checking  presence in ['entities']['hashtags']['text']

Iterate over streaming_tweets_objects to get the tweets and its metadata.

```
for tweet in r.iter_lines():
    if tweet:
        tweet_data = json.loads(tweet)
```

Now you can get all the tags you want from tweet data json string.

Comment: how to store that tweets in a file

Comment: the 'streaming_tweets_objects" variable returns a value Response[200]

Comment: You need to iterate over this object

Comment: I have edited my reply above for reference. Hope this helps !